# JavaScript filter array with filters of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm currently trying to filter an array by multiple filters stored in another array.
A filter-object contains the name of the attribute we want to filter, the operator and the condition.
So it could look like this:

```js
let filters = [{
  attribute: 'id',
  operator: '<',
  condition: 5
}, {
  attribute: 'name',
  operator: '=',
  condition: 'Max'
}]
```

And the Array with the item could look like this:

```js
const items = [{
  id: 0,
  name: 'Max',
  nachname: 'Maier'
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Peter',
  nachname: 'Huber'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Max',
  nachname: 'Brooks'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'Sara',
  nachname: 'Scott'
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: 'Peter',
  nachname: 'Evans'
}]
```

Can you please help me out?

My current solutions (see below) always returns all elements. So it doesn't filter anything.

```
items.filter((item) => {
    filters.forEach((filter) => {
      switch (filter.operator) {
        case '<':
          if (!(item[filter.attribute] < filter.condition)) return false
          break
        case '<=':
          if (!(item[filter.attribute] <= filter.condition)) return false
          break
        case '=':
          if (!(item[filter.attribute] === filter.condition)) return false
          break
        case '>':
          if (!(item[filter.attribute] > filter.condition)) return false
          break
        case '>=':
          if (!(item[filter.attribute] >= filter.condition)) return false
          break
        case '*wildcard*':
          if (!item[filter.attribute].includes(filter.condition))
            return false
          break
      }
    })
    return true
  })
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that `forEach` callback function return values are not used.

Sounds like what you'd want instead is to use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) on your `filters` array for every item in `items`

```js
const filters = [{"attribute":"id","operator":"<","condition":5},{"attribute":"name","operator":"=","condition":"Max"}]

const items = [{"id":0,"name":"Max","nachname":"Maier"},{"id":1,"name":"Peter","nachname":"Huber"},{"id":2,"name":"Max","nachname":"Brooks"},{"id":3,"name":"Sara","nachname":"Scott"},{"id":4,"name":"Peter","nachname":"Evans"}]

const filtered = items.filter(item =>
  filters.every(({ attribute, operator, condition }) => {
    switch (operator) {
      case "<":
        return item[attribute] < condition
      case ">":
        return item[attribute] > condition
      case "=":
        return item[attribute] == condition
      // and so on
    }
    return true
  })
)

console.info(filtered)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important }
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) Works like a charme!

Answer (score 2):

You need to return a boolean from the filter callback based on the filters. Right now you are just always returning `true` from the callback function passed to filter.

Try something like this:

```js
const doesItemPassFilter = item => filter => {
  // your filter logic
}

items.filter(item => filters.every(doesItemPassFilter(item)));
```

I've based my concept that your filters are "and"'s - meaning that an item has to match them all. If your filters are "or"'s - meaning that an item has to match at least one filter - then just change `every` to `some`.

Comment: OP's `return false` on each negated condition check suggests that they do want an `AND` evaluation